# loading package (much) slower with miktex 21.6

Tags: packages, miktex

I have moved from miktex 2.9 to 21.6
I get much slower compilation, even for shortest documents. I realized that most of the time is spent in loading packages (see the packages I use below). With a quite recent windows laptop, compilation starts after more than 8 seconds with Miktex 21.6 and less than 4 with Miktex 2.9. With old machine running Ubuntu, I get less than 2 sec.

I read a few things about slow compilations on windows but nothing really relevant since the problem here is about package loading. Moreover, I get same results on a second compilation. So that issue seems not related to package updating.

Of course, 8 seconds is not that long but this starts to be really annoying while testing. For example, playing with requires to compile often for very small changes. Hence compilation delay slows down the process a lot.

Any help is welcome!

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyClass}

%%%%%%%%%%%%  OPTIONS  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\pt@size{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\pt@size{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\pt@size{12pt}}
\DeclareOption{14pt}{\def\pt@size{14pt}}
\ProcessOptions
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\LoadClass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[frenchb]{babel} %%%% needed for spaces

\RequirePackage{savesym}
\let\checkmark\undefined
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{svrsymbols}
\let\Cross\undefined
 \RequirePackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{dingbat}
\RequirePackage{adforn}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{empheq}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{caption,subcaption}
\RequirePackage{caption,setspace}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{extsizes}
\RequirePackage[left=1.cm , top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=1.cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[export]{adjustbox}
\RequirePackage{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{environ}

%%% GRAPHS SCHEMAS CHEMISTRY %%%
\RequirePackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\RequirePackage{chemfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,shapes.geometric,3d}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

%%% HIGHLIGHT %%%
\RequirePackage{soul}

%%% UNITS %%%
%---- Package pour une bonne typographie des unités
\RequirePackage[load-configurations = abbreviations,separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx} %unités + abbréviations
%Utilisation de la typographie fracaise même police que dans le texte
\sisetup{locale = FR,
%même police que dans le texte
    detect-all,
%Point centré comme séparateur d'unités
    inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{.}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: `MiKTeX 21.6`, comme son numéro l'indique, est sorti il y a quelques jours.

Comment: the first compilation of a day is always slower as miktex seem to recreate the formats regularly, but even the following are noticibly  slower than in texlive. In part it is caused by more file lookups done by latex (which will be reduced in the next latex), but for the rest I don't know. I would advise to install texlive in parallel if speed is needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried with texlive and results are quite similar. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my class file?

Comment: is your latex up-to-date? And do you use some tool like latexmk?

Comment: I guess latex is up-to-date since I made a new install, looked for update using miktex console and updated avery thing. I did not know latexmk. What I've read is that latexmk is not about package loading. But I might be wrong.